# Why is re not working on my file?

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regular expression to remove all the apostrophes in my textfile. I need to encode it in utf-8 for my other functions to work. So when I try this:

```
 import re
 import codecs

 dataset=[]
 with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', 'utf8') as fil:
    for line in fil:
        lines=[re.sub("'","",line) for line in fil]
        print(lines)
        dataset.append(lines.lower().strip().split())
```

Output:

```
[] #on printing lines
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preproc.py", line 112, in <module>
    dataset.append(lines.lower().strip().split())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Textfile contains a string like this: `It's an amazing day she's said`
It returns the same thing back to me on printing line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a SO chat session, the question is really this. Given a list of lists of words, how do you replace the unicode apostrophe's and maintain the original data structure.

Given this data structure, strip out the `\u2019` unicode characters

```
s = [[u'wasn\u2019t', u'right', u'part', u'say', u'things', 
      u'she\u2019s', u'hurt', u'terribly', u'she\u2019s', 
      u'speaking']]
```

Here's one working example of how to do this:

```
quotes_to_remove = [u"'", u"\u2019", u"\u2018"]
new_s = []
for line in s:
    new_line = []
    for word in line:
        for quote in quotes_to_remove:
            word = word.replace(quote, "")
        new_line.append(word)
    new_s.append(new_line)
print(new_s)
```

produces:

```
[[u'wasnt', u'right', u'part', u'say', u'things', u'shes', 
  u'hurt', u'terribly', u'shes', u'speaking']]
```

Also worth noting is that the asker is working in python 2.7.10 and the code provided in this answer is not tested on python 3.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question. I am looking at appending the words back into a list for further processing. On trying the 1st code above as added in the edited question, it tells me that lines is empty and neither can I work with dataset.append.

Comment: Can you add the output of the updated script in your original post when you run it?

Comment: You did not copy my code correctly.  Please get rid of the `for line in fil` in your script.

Comment: What does this code produce?    

    import re
    import codecs

    with codecs.open("textfile.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
        lines = [re.sub("'", "", line) for line in f]
        print(lines)

Comment: It is producing: [u'football\u2019s is awesome isn\u2019t it']

The sentence was: football's is awesome isn't it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105069/discussion-between-eric-dill-and-minks).

Answer (score 1):

I think it can work like this:

```
import re
import codecs

with codecs.open("textfile.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
       f[i] = re.sub("'","",line)
    print(line)
```

You original method will not assign value to list f successfully.
I have make two easy experiment for you.

1.

```
list1 = [2,3,5,4,1,1,1,2,2,5,1]

for num in list1:
    num = 1

print(list1)
```

output: [2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1]

2.

```
list1 = [2,3,5,4,1,1,1,2,2,5,1]

for i, num in enumerate(list1):
    list1[i] = 1

print(list1)
```

output: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

So that is why your result is wrong. This is not regex question! Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Hi, I am receiving this error:

 File "preproc.py", line 110, in <module>
    fil[i]=re.sub("'","",line)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 716, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__setitem__'

Comment: In fact, I am not quite sure what is your problem now? I remember your original problem is not like this haha. Can you describe your question more specific again for me? Thank you. :)